# Python syntax error with assignment

Tags: python, syntax-error

I got a feeling I'm going to feel stupid when the answers come back, but I am really confused.

I have reduced the python (2.6.4) code to the following:

```
k = 0  
if k == 1:  
   k = 0  
else:  
   k = 1  
k = 3
```

I get a syntax error at `k = 3`.  What an I missing.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Works fine as written.

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of the error

Comment: Are you pasting this into the interactive interpreter? If so, you'll need to add *newlines* after any top-level compound statement, so after `k = 1`.

Comment: i think, there is a indentation problem.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using the interactive interpreter.  You need a blank line before `k = 3`:

```
>>> k = 0
>>> if k == 1:
...    k = 0
... else:
...    k = 1
... k = 3
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    k = 3
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> k = 0
>>> if k == 1:
...    k = 0
... else:
...    k = 1
...
>>> k = 3
```

This tells Python that the `if...else` statement is finished.

Note that this is only necessary in the interpreter.  Python does not pay attention to vertical line space like this when reading normal source files.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.  I tried it as you said and it worked just fine.  The source of the problem is a python file on a web server (apache).  There is a little more to the code, but with or without the extra line the interpreter just bails.  I don't know if it is the syntax problem or not.

Comment: OK, I got it and yes I do feel stupid.  Here is an example

    dict = {'l':'test','m':'test_again'}
    for key in dict:
        if key == 'l':
           dict['k'] = 'test_also'

It really doesn't like changing the size of the dictionary.

Comment: You cannot change the size of a dictionary while iterating over it.  This screws up Python's iteration protocol.  Instead, you need to make a new dictionary from the values in the old one.